# In Flutter, how to share the text using share_plus in a the format that I want

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently building a password manager using Flutter. I have used share_plus.dart package , to share the passwords stored by the user. I have 4 text fields in my password, they are : title, email, password(userpassword), and url.

When I share them, they get displayed in a not good looking format. So,I want to display, the text shared using the share button on my flutter app in a particular format.

The format, I want:

```
Title: value
Email: value
Password: value
url: value
```

My code:

```
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              final text = _titleController.text + _emailController.text + _userPasswordController.text + _urlController.text;
              if (_password == null || text.isEmpty) {
                await showCannotShareEmptyPasswordDialog(context);
              } else {
                Share.share(text);
              }
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
          ),
```

Comment: what is not good about the format? The four text are right next to eachother without space, right? How do you want to split the 4 texts? Where is the share text going to? Into an email?

Comment: It currently gets shared as `Login for Twitter chrisgomes28027@gmail.comChrisgomesTweettwitter.com`     I have written the format I want above. Yeah, into an email, into WhatsApp, etc.

Comment: In web build, only open email, It dos not open whats app or telegram or other messaging app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Share.share("Title: $Title"\n Email: $value" \n);
```

Try using this, this might help you

in my case i did like this

```
ShareClass.shareMethod(
        message:
        "Join me on App! It is an awesome and secure app we can use to connect with each other Download it at: ${Platform.isAndroid ? "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id" : "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/app"}");
  }
```